# VMware Workstation - interoperability of VMs

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

(I've looked through the posts for the question that I'm submitting, but couldn't see one.)  I'm new to VMware Workstation and to virtualization in general.  If I create a virtual machine on the MS Windows version of Workstation (Win7 and Workstation 9), can a friend use the MS Windows virtual machine with the Linux version of Workstation installed on his laptop (Debian 6 ("Squeeze") and Workstation 9)?  Thanks!

Bob

Comment: Thanks so much DavidBaumann and Zoredache for responding so quickly!

Comment: Do you want to set something as solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he should be able to.
Even if he uses an older version, you can downgrade before you copy it.

The problem might be Windows, because different CPUs may cause trouble. If you have a better CPU and create the VM there, it might not run on an older cpu, also switching from AMD to INTEL might cause problems.
Also a 64 bit guest requires a 64 bit host!

So in fact, VMWare is not the problem, but the windows guest.
Also you should think about licensing.
If you share a linux guest, there's no problem. Change CPU type, count, ram, vmware/virtualbox just like you want.

Comment: Having different CPUs should not be a problem for any current OS (Vista and above).  Not having a 64 bit CPU on the host, but having a 64 bit guest would be a problem, but Vmware Workstation 9, basically requires a CPU with VM features, and pretty much every CPU with these features are also 64 bit capable.

Answer (score 1):

> If I create a virtual machine on the MS Windows version of Workstation (Win7 and Workstation 9), can a friend use the MS Windows virtual machine with the Linux version of Workstation installed on his laptop (Debian 6 ("Squeeze") and Workstation 9)?

Taking VMs from Workstation 9 on Windows to Linux or the other way around works just fine.  Keep in mind that you should shutdown the VM before you transfer it.  Since a suspended VM will only start if the host system cpu/ram has not changed.

Also keep in mind that any snapshots you take cannot be shared.  So remove/commit any snapshots before transferring the VM.  (See my question about [Workstation and snapshots](https://superuser.com/questions/587738/transfer-vm-with-snapshots-to-another-system))

Vmware guests have a 'hardware' version.  If either you or your friend updates to a newer version of Workstation in the future, you should not increase the hardware version of that guest until you have updated any systems that will use that guest to the a version of workstation that will support that hardware version.